# How to validate list of name, value paired json object using data annotations or fluent api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I have this json data:

```
{
  "productCharacteristic": [
    {
      "name": "CustomerName",
      "value": "Lucy"
    },
    {
      "name": "ODBNo.",
      "value": "RIY-FALA-8180-01-7697-00"
    },
    {
      "name": "DBID",
      "value": "D0376409401"
    },
    {
      "name": "Carrier",
      "value": "Zain"
    },
    {
      "name": "OperationRegion",
      "value": "RIYADH"
    },
    {
      "name": "OperationCompany",
      "value": "Safari_ISP_Dispatcher"
    }
  ]
}
```

Validation condition:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|      Name           |Optional/Mandatory|     Value                                |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|   CustomerName      |   Mandatory      |The value consists of 3 to 64 characters. |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|   ODBNo             |   Mandatory      |Type:text length <= 24                    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|   DBID              |   Optional       |Type:text, length <= 20                   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|   Carrier           |   Mandatory      |The value consists of 1 to 64 characters. |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|   OperationRegion   |   Optional       |The value consists of 1 to 64 characters. |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|   OperationCompany  |   Mandatory      |The value consists of 1 to 64 characters. |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
```

Controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(RootObj model)
{
    var data = model;
    return Ok(data);
}
```

I have created these classes to map this json data:

```
public class RootObj
{
    public Productcharacteristic[] productCharacteristic { get; set; }
}

public class Productcharacteristic
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can't understand how can I write the validation rules using **data annotations** or **fluent api** in this class.

Can anybody have any idea, how to write validation rules for this type of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom data annotation validator by extending ValidationAttribute, something like this:

[This sample code is not tested]

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public CustomValidationAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Get the dependent property 
        var name = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(_name);
        // Get the value of the dependent property 
        var nameValue = name.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        string strValue = value as string;
        if (nameValue.ToLower() == "customer")
        {
            return strValue.Length => 3 && strValue.Length <= 64
                        ? Validation.Success;
                        : ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else if (nameValue.ToLower() == "odbno")
        {
            //etc...
        }
        .....
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this::

```
public class Productcharacteristic
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    [CustomValidation("name", ErrorMessage("Invalid..."))]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it helps;